# Web browsers with same or similar features like Opera on Presto engine

Tags: linux, windows-7, web-browser

Are there any active, up-to-date web browsers which have the following capabilities (all present in Opera 12.x and older versions):

- separately block / allow image display on each open tab (some tabs will have images blocked, some won't, and some will display cached images)
- ignore a site's built in CSS, and apply your own (again, on individual tabs). Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzUk6.jpg).
- disable JavaScript & plug-ins, sending of referrer information, animated images, sound in webpages (all were accessible in Opera by pressing F12)

If none of the new browsers have these capabilities, are there any add-ons for, say, Firefox, which can provide what I'm looking for?

<del>It should run on Windows XP, though I'll settle for something that I could run on Ubuntu 16 (through VirtualBox).</del>

It should run on Windows 7, or any Linux distro.

**EDIT**

I am aware of Firefox's Reader view option and View > Page Style > No Style option. That's not quite what I have in mind, though it does ignore a site's CSS.

Comment: The settings per tab: That means that they stay if you load a different page in the same tab, correct? For example, if I provide custom CSS for a Wikipedia page opened, and I click an external link that opens in the same tab, the custom CSS will be applied to the external page, too, correct?

Comment: @unor That is correct. That is correct. Something like this: http://imgur.com/a/6FYsT . The top image is stackoverflow.com with custom css (C64-like display), while the bottom one is bbc.co.uk loaded in the same tab.

Answer (score 1):

Opera is getting better every release. But so is Vivaldi. Vivaldi is currently the go-to browser for those who loved Opera 12. Also Brave -browser is a strong newcomer!

But to answer your question - one word: Vivaldi!

Comment: Vivaldi is a joke of a browser, pretty much the same crap as Opera 15+. For starter, it doesn't fulfills any single feature requested by the OP.